# delete a form instance from a list(of form)

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, generic-list

`Dim fList As New List(Of Form)`

every time I hit a marker..

```
Dim f As New Form2
Me.AddOwnedForm(f)
fList.Add(f)
f.Show()
```

I create an instance and add it to the `fList`..

however, if I close that particular instance.. it stays to the `fList` and whenever I hit a certain event that calls out all from the list, the supposedly *closed* form appears..

here is the flow of my program :

Click marker --> show form, add to list
Drag map --> hides forms
mouseLeave --> shows hidden forms
but when I manually close the form, when I *Drag and MouseLeave* it appears again.

Question is : How can I delete the added instance to the `fList` if I close it?

*It should only appear if it was opened again through clicking the marker. hope you get what I mean. Thanks!*

Answer (score 2):

If you still have a reference to the form object:

```
fList.Remove(f) 'f is a reference to a form object
```

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e(v=vs.110).aspx

If you know the index of the form in the List:

```
fList.RemoveAt(index) 'removes the item at position of index
```

Documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx

If you want to remove by Text you can use the first method to do something like this:

```
For Each f as Form in fList
    If f.Text = "foo" Then fList.Remove(f)
    Exit For
Next
```

Or using Linq:

```
fList.RemoveAll(Function(x) x.Text = "foo")
```

Comment: will this work? `fList.Remove(f.text=some variable)` and if it is, where should I place it? - I need it to remove after I click X on the form instance..

Comment: No that will not work, if you check the documentation that I liked to there is no method that accepts a Boolean argument. See my updated answer on how to do this.

Comment: I do not give names and IDs to my elements in the list, I'm new in using this, but this might work. I need to study first. thanks. but I am looking on `fList.Clear()` and only add currently `Visible` forms to the list so that those will be the ones to get pulled out. will that do good? also, I can't forsee where should I put the code so it will fire when I close the instance.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Matt Miko's answer should be the best suited, but I cannot apply it to how I created my list. Anyway, I solved the problem.

Since I need to delete the form element in `fList` which was the one that was closed..

```
Public fList As New List(Of Form)
```

then added this code in `Form2`:

```
Form1.fList.Remove(Me)
```

didn't know this was possible, but it worked for me.

if you can see it logically, if I hit X on the form, it will remove *that* form from the list. so that my program will only show the chosen forms. :)

Comment: This is just using the first option I posted in my answer as you are passing a reference to a specific form instance to the remove method

Comment: I thought of the first option as something that I can just add to the code. but since my list doesn't have names, that will remove I don't know which one. lol